# How to pipe the output of icat to the file command in bash

Tags: bash, file

I am trying this

```
icat -o <OFFSET> <IMAGE_NAME> <INODE> | file
```

in order to get file info from the "icated" file

I also tried

```
icat -o <OFFSET> <IMAGE_NAME> <INODE> | file -f -
icat -o <OFFSET> <IMAGE_NAME> <INODE> | xargs file
```

and no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `icat` returns the contents of a file, you can use:

```
icat -o <OFFSET> <IMAGE_NAME> <INODE> | file -
```

The `-f` argument to `file` has a different purpose: it tells `file` to read file names from the file given as an argument to `-f`.